# Cloudflare edge certificates stuck on pending validation because of DNSSEC

Tags: cloudflare, dnssec

I’ve added my domain to cloudflare around 15 hours ago and edge certificates is still stuck on pending.
I tried the help center and the answer I got was to test my website with https://letsdebug.net/ and it returns error:

"no keys have a DS with algorithm ECDSAP256SHA256 from ip.ip.ip.ip for key domain.com while building chain of trust"

```
DNSLookupFailed
A fatal issue occurred during the DNS lookup process for domain.com/CAA.
DNS response for domain.com had fatal DNSSEC issues: validation failure <novaboosting.com. CAA IN>: no keys have a DS with algorithm ECDSAP256SHA256 from ip.ip.ip.ip for key domain.com. while building chain of trust. Additionally, Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 resolver reported: no SEP matching the DS found for domain.com.
```

and

```
TXTRecordError
An error occurred while attempting to lookup the TXT record on _acme-challenge.domain.com . Any resolver errors that the Let's Encrypt CA encounters on this record will cause certificate issuance to fail.

DNS response for _acme-challenge.domain.com had fatal DNSSEC issues: validation failure <_acme-challenge.novaboosting.com. TXT IN>: no keys have a DS with algorithm ECDSAP256SHA256 from ip.ip.ip.ip for key domain.com. while building chain of trust. Additionally, Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 resolver reported: no SEP matching the DS found for domain.com.
```

I changed the domain name and ips to be safe

In my domain registrar there is no option to enable DNSSEC and I can’t even do advanced DNS records because I don’t use default nameservers it says

any idea what the problem is and how can I solve this?

domain name is novaboosting.com